# 「個人を特定できる情報を明示的/暗黙的な同意なしに保存するCookie」とは？

Tags: internet-explorer, cookie

IEのCookieの設定（プライバシ）で以下のような設定があります

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- 個人を特定できる情報を明示的な同意なしに保存するCookie
- 個人を特定できる情報を暗黙的な同意なしに保存するCookie

これらはどのように作ったCookieの事を言うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

そもそも Cookie というのは Web Server が作成して Web UA に送りつけたデータを Web UA が Web Server に送り返すだけの代物です。
なので Cookie は「個人を特定できる情報」をブラウザ等から「盗み出す」ことはありません。
というわけで Cookie 自体は危険なものではありません。これをふまえて：

その辺の文言の意味は P3P (The Platform for Privacy Preferences) という文書が規定しています。
https://www.iajapan.org/trans2japanese/w3c/rec-p3p-20020416j.html
端的には Web Contents 提供側が「ウチはプライバシーを尊重しています」という宣言をユーザー側に自動的に提供するものです。
（サイト運営者が本当に宣言どおりに守っているかどうかはまったく別の話ですけど）

具体的にどういうものなのかは提示 P3P 文書の 1.1.2 P3P 利用例とか 3.1 ポリシーの例とかを参照。

プライバシー宣言は XML で完全記述してもいいのですけどサイズがでかくなるので
コンパクトな表現が規定されていて (同 4) 
提示のダイアログにも「コンパクトなプライバシーポリシー」なる用語が出ていますね。

なので質問の

> どのように作った Cookie

に対する回答は「 P3P 文書に基づいて必要な宣言を行って作った Cookie 」となるでしょうか。
Web サイトに P3P プライバシー ポリシーを導入する方法
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms537341(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 既にわかっている人向け解説になっているかもしれない・・・

Comment: Cookie 自体にプライバシー情報が格納されているわけではないです。プライバシー情報が残っているのはあくまで Web Server 側で、そのプライバシー情報のうち特定目的で使うものを有効にするには Web UA 側に Cookie を残す必要がある、という使い方を想定しています。ユーザーは（複数存在するであろう） Cookie のうち、使用目的Ａなものは容認し、使用目的Ｂなものは容認しない、という選択をするための機能です。

Answer (score 4):

774RRさんの回答が全てだと思います。

この回答は補足的なものとして見て頂ければ幸いですが、「**明示的な同意**」とは、最初は空欄だった「プライバシ情報の収集・利用許可」チェックボックスをユーザーが自身の操作でオンにしたような場合（オプトイン属性の要件）で、「**暗黙的な同意**」とは、デフォルトでオンになっている「プライバシ情報の収集・利用許可」チェックボックスをそのままにして［OK］ボタンを押したような場合（オプトアウト属性の要件）のことです。

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fwin2k/experiments/ie6privacy/ie6privacy_09.html